# What kind of data structure is used by the SQLite in-memory database?

Tags: data-structures, sqlite

Does it use the B-tree and pages as the disk-based database?
Does it use the index?\
Thank you!

Comment: Did you take a look at https://sqlite.org/?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it seems no document talks about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An in-memory database uses *exactly* the same data structures as a disk-based database.
The only difference is that the pages in the pager cache are never written to a file.